# accessing object json.`params` (reserved keyword) from (dynamic)json in c#

Tags: c#, json

I am calling an api which returns some json.
The format of the received json is as follows:

```
{
  "method": "depth.update",
  "params": [
    true,
    {
      "asks": [
        [
          "8000.00",
          "9.6250"
        ]
      ],
      "bids": [
        [
          "8000.00",
          "9.6250"
        ]
      ]
    },
    "EOS_USDT"
  ],
  "id": null
}
```

Note the Object `params`with asks and bids, which I am trying to access.

The json is beeing deserialized into a dynamic.

As shown in the example below, I can access the objects by calling `json.method` for instance.

```
// retrieve response
string message = Receivestring();
// deserialize
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(message);
// check if we are in the correct method
if (json.method == "depth.update")
{
    // -> this does not work <--
    dynamic parameters = json.params;
}
else if (json.method == "other.method")
{
    dynamic success = json.result;
}
```

issue:
`json.params` will not work. I guess it is a reserved keyword, Visual Studio tries to match.
How can I access `json.params` then?

Comment: Can't you set a breakpoint and look at generated members?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest not to use `dynamic` if you know your data-structure at compile-time.

Comment: @McNets I can do that and `params` is within the generated members. However, `params` is reserved by visual studio. I cant use it. But D-Shih supplied an answer already.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain Unfortunately, I do not know the data-structure at run time. The server might send updates in completely different structures, which are defined by the `method` parameter

Comment: "I do not know the data-structure at run time" well, you know it has `params`, `method`, and `result`. It's fine to define a class with members that may not be present in the JSON in all cases (they would just be null).

Comment: but you need to read that structure anyway. So you *have* to know it at some point.

Comment: this is an interesting suggestion. I do not know what I would do if `params` in `method:"depth.update"` equals `(bool, Bids[],Asks[],CurrencyPair)` but in `method:"kline.update",`  equals `(DateTime,double,double,double,double,double,double,string)`. I will look into this though. Right now I try to determine the type of object received by `json.method` and fill my own object with it's data accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `params` is a keyword for c#, you can try to use `@` to escape [keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/)

```
json.@params
```